# createUrl() issue yii

Tags: php, yii, routes

I try to make header links using `createUrl()` method.
I have subdomain 'account'.

When I use `$this->createUrl('account/default/index')` it works correct. 
But I want create link when I locating on http://account.example.com to http://example.com/about.

Can I do that using `createUrl()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try in your rules makes route:

> ```
> 'http://site.com/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 
>                                                'site/<controller>/<action>'
> ```

Than for creating url `http://site.com/about` use `Yii::app()->request->createUrl('site/about/index')`